# Passing cmd line params to storm subprocesses

Tags: java, apache-storm

I need to have some values passed on the cmd line to the various worker processes that storm starts when a topology gets submitted. I've edited the **/opt/storm/bin/storm** file to add the params to the initial supervisor process but these values aren't being propagated to the subsequent workers.

Suggestions on where to look?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: the param is in **conf/storm.yaml**.

Add your worker cmd line params to *worker.childopts*.

EG: `worker.childopts: "-Duser.timezone=UTC"`

A list of all default params is [here](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml).